# how to identify what view was clicked(button,textview,imageview) in a listview raw with simpleadapter

Tags: android

Im using a listview with simpleadapter in each listview row there is a layout that contains 3 buttons ane one textview how can i get the inner listview row widjet that was clicked in the onitemclicked method, i dont want to use my own costume adapter is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

no. `onItemClicked` is for the whole view. If you need individual separation you must create your own custom adapter and properly set `OnClickListener` for each of the button inside that view.